# Can I use a Sharepoint server as a development machine?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is it possible that can I use Sharepoint server as development machine also. My mananger has asked me to use one of the newly purchased server for Sharepoint server as well as sharepoint development.

In future we will do some small development so what type of installation do I need?
Please guide me for the following which one I should install or which one is not required.

1. Standalone or Farms
2. VM
3. SQL Server 2008
4. VS 2010

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 can run on a 64-Bit Windows 7, as per [instructions from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx).

It does not work on 32 Bit Windows as SharePoint 2010 is 64-Bit only, and it does not work on Vista.

Comment: Thanx for reply. Yes, I will install it on Windows Server 2008. My question is about installtion type standalone or Farms and I will use the same server for development. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use your SharePoint server as a development machine. I'd suggest using a VM as it allows you to quickly and easily switch between, revert and deploy setups should something go wrong (and things WILL go wrong with SharePoint).

At work, my machine runs Win Server 2008 and I remote into a Hyper-V hosted VM which itself runs Server 2008 - I develop and run SP on that VM. Since I have SP, SQL Server and VS2010 all running on it at the same time, I allocate the VM at least 5.5 GB of memory (and it's still hungry for more).

Comment: Thank you very mcuh for reply. So you mean I will go for Farms installation instead of Standalone?

Comment: I'd say that which one you use should be determined by what your users will use... at work we use a Farms deployment. I don't know much about standalone, but as far as I know, it forces you to use SQL Server Express and restricts your db size to 4 GB. And by definition, a standalone deployment can only span one machine. I doubt standalone is sufficient in most cases.

Comment: Mr. Nathan! Thank you for detail reply. My users will be the top manangement and they are mostly intresting in some main business reports and document sharing. For reporinting i will have to connect some other sql databases so i think farms installation will be good choice in my case. There will be minimum use of Sharepoint so I want to use the same server machine for development as well as sharepoint server. I am very new and just start learning Sharepoint by using internet help.

Comment: Yeah, if you're using existing databases and your workplace has a SQL Server license, I'd recommend choosing farm deployment. Good luck anyway, SharePoint is massive and there's a fairly big learning curve. I only started on it a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: Thanx agian for reply and Good luck to you also. abnasir@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can develop for SharePoint 2010 on a Windows 2008 Server x64 or on a Windows 7 64bit.  A Windows 7 is of course only recommended for development.

Most developers use a standalone machine for their SharePoint 2010 development. Creating a farm is complex and $$.

Personally I develop in virtual machines. I have on clean vm image that I copy for every new project (client). You need a powerful computer to run these virtual machines. At least 4GB memory and a recent multicore cpu.

You will need Visual Studio 2010, SQL server and ofcourse SharePoint. Office can also be handy but is not needed. SQl server express is included in Visual Studio and the SharePoint install also installs SQl server if needed. Certain Visual Studio versions include an "SQL server developer" license.

Comment: Thanx for reply. I want to use the same SP Server for development machine also only for SP. May be in future they company will think about standalone development machine for SP. Sharing documents by departments and compnany's website are the factors to go for Sharepoint. So during instalation which option will more suitable for me Standalone installation or Farms Installation?